# Codable with noisy JSON response

Tags: json, swift, codable

Generally, I understand how `Codable` works. A simple example would be:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Paul",
        "photo": {
            "id": 48,
            "url": "https://..."
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Andrew",
        "photo": {
            "id": 389,
            "url": "https://..."
        }
    }
]
```

which would require two simple structs:

```swift
struct User: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var photo: Photo
}

struct Photo: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var url: String
}
```

---

Given the example above, my API's response json comes in a more complicated format:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "data": {
                "id": 1,
                "attributes": {
                    "name": "Paul"
                },
                "relationships": {
                    "photo": {
                        "data": {
                            "id": 48,
                            "attributes": {
                                "url": "https://..."
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "id": 2,
                "attributes": {
                    "name": "Andrew"
                },
                "relationships": {
                    "photo": {
                        "data": {
                            "id": 389,
                            "attributes": {
                                "url": "https://..."
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've played around with [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to pre-parse / flatten the json by removing all the noise and trying to make the format like in the first json example. However, I feel like there's probably a better, more obvious way to do it, and manipulating the json seems very error prone.

I've read about CodingKeys, but at this point, that's almost as much extra work as it would be to parse the json all manually using SwiftyJSON.

Does anyone know how to do this *efficiently*?

Comment: Why are you posting json and code that is not relevant for the question and what is really so problematic about that json? You certainly won’t need and CodingKey enums for this.

Comment: I'm trying to give context, that's all. And I'm not very familiar with CodingKeys. Problematic is that it's overly complex and I don't know how to parse it.

Comment: check out here https://github.com/jatinfl15/Codable/blob/main/Codable.swift i created codable struct for your noisy json. but please follow the @JoakimDanielson comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) to generate the response models for you from the specified JSON.

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Root
struct Root: Codable {
    let data: [Datum]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable {
    let data: DatumData
}

// MARK: - DatumData
struct DatumData: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let attributes: PurpleAttributes
    let relationships: Relationships
}

// MARK: - PurpleAttributes
struct PurpleAttributes: Codable {
    let name: String
}

// MARK: - Relationships
struct Relationships: Codable {
    let photo: Photo
}

// MARK: - Photo
struct Photo: Codable {
    let data: PhotoData
}

// MARK: - PhotoData
struct PhotoData: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let attributes: FluffyAttributes
}

// MARK: - FluffyAttributes
struct FluffyAttributes: Codable {
    let url: String
}

let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson good catch, updated